# Deoplete + Vimtex with Lazy.nvim. Deoplete is not triggered

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimtex, lazyvim, plugin-deoplete

I tried to migrate fomr packer.nvim to lazy.nvim and I encounter problem with deoplete. With packer is triggered on every document and `.tex` files. With `Lazy.nvim` is not.

I appreciate any help!

Here is my nvim tree:

```
 .
├──  init.lua
├──  lazy-lock.json
└──  lua
   └──  mafsi
      ├──  lazy.lua
      └──  plugins
         ├──  colorscheme.lua
         ├──  deoplete.lua
         └──  vimtex.lua
```

Here are my files:

`init.lua`

```lua
-- Set Neovim's runtime path to include the config directory
vim.cmd("set runtimepath^=~/.config/nvim")

-- Set Neovim's pack path to include the config directory
vim.cmd("set packpath^=~/.config/nvim")

vim.g.python3_host_prog = '/usr/local/bin/python3'

vim.o.completeopt = "noinsert,menuone,noselect"

require("mafsi.lazy")
```

`lazy.lua`

```lua
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup("mafsi.plugins")
```

`vimtex.lua`

```lua
-- Assuming 'lazy.nvim' uses a table configuration similar to 'packer.nvim'
return {
  -- The plugin repository
  "lervag/vimtex",
  -- Conditions for lazy loading (this will depend on 'lazy.nvim' API)
  -- event = "BufRead *.tex",

  -- Plugin configuration function
  config = function()
    -- Automatically complete braces when typing LaTeX
    vim.g.vimtex_complete_close_braces = 1

    -- Set the compiler method for Vimtex to latexmk
    vim.g.vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'

    -- there are warning messages and no error messages.
    -- Control whether or not to automatically open the |quickfix| window in case
    vim.g.vimtex_quickfix_open_on_warning = 0

    -- Choose which program to use to view PDF file
    vim.g.vimtex_view_method = 'skim'

    -- Value 1 allows forward search after every successful compilation
    vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_sync = 1

    -- Value 1 allows change focus to skim after command `:VimtexView` is given
    vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_activate = 1
  end,
}
```

`deoplete.lua`

```lua
return {
  'Shougo/deoplete.nvim',
  -- Define when to load the plugin, e.g., on certain command or event.
  -- event = "InsertEnter", -- or another appropriate event or command
  config = function()
    -- Enable Deoplete at startup
    vim.g["deoplete#enable_at_startup"] = 1

    -- Configure Deoplete for Vimtex
    vim.call("deoplete#custom#var", "omni", "input_patterns", {
      tex = vim.g["vimtex#re#deoplete"]
    })
  end,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main issue here is the use of the `config` key to lazy.nvim for configuring things. In particular, I suspect that you need to set `deploete#enable_at_startup` to 1 earlier than the `config` function is executed.

I think in general that you should consider to use the `init` key instead of the `config` key for the configuration that simply sets options. That is, only use the `config` key for things that are safe to postpone.

This, you should use something like this:

```lua
-- vimtex.lua
return {
  "lervag/vimtex",
  init = function()
    vim.g.vimtex_complete_close_braces = 1
    vim.g.vimtex_quickfix_open_on_warning = 0
    vim.g.vimtex_view_method = 'skim'
    vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_sync = 1
    vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_activate = 1
  end,
}

-- deoplete.lua
return {
  'Shougo/deoplete.nvim',
  init = function()
    vim.g["deoplete#enable_at_startup"] = 1
  end,
  config = function()
    vim.fn["deoplete#custom#var"]("omni", "input_patterns", {
      tex = vim.g["vimtex#re#deoplete"]
    })
  end,
}
```

Here the call to `deplote#custom#var` should not be done until after the plugin is loaded, so it can't go in the `init` block.

I removed your comments; feel free to add them back if you need them. I prefer to avoid comments, especially when you can simply do `:help <c-r><c-w><cr>` to get the full docs instead. I also removed some unnecessary code.

PS! Just to be clear, you should *not* lazy load VimTeX, so don't use any of the `event`, `ft`, `keys`, or `cmd` keys from the lazy specs!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried 2 days to make it work. You saved the week!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)